# Weird Reactjs state behaviour when accessing it from outside render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm working on a simple drawing example, where the user can draw straight lines by clicking and dragging.

One of the features I want to implement is the ability to delete a line by double clicking on it, the problem I have is removing such line from the state array, I have a bare bones [example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/floorplan-creator-v1b69?file=/src/DrawingTools.js).

Unfortunately, when I try to `console.log()` the state array `allPaths` the app freezes but that doesn't happen on my local setup.

For example:

1. User draw 4 lines
2. On double click on the first line the console logs, its ID and empty state array[]
3. On double click the fourth line the log displays line ID and state array of length 3, that contains the first 3 lines, but it does not show the entire array... ?

On my local setup, when I `console.log(allPaths)` on doubleclick I get the `allPaths` state before that particular lines has been created, it doesn't show all entries, but when I `log` in the render method it shows all entries fine.

I have no idea what I'm doing wrong ...

Comment: `JSON.stringify` the log in the `useEffect` instead of logging `allPaths` directly--in the sandbox that fixes one freeze I was seeing.

Comment: @DaveNewton, that works better, but it does not solve the problem, the array `allPaths` is returning the elements created before that particular line I'm trying to remove, even though `allPaths` is a state array

Comment: Didn't say it did ;) Just a general debug tip when hitting loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In every render cycle you create new layers, instead use a ref to keep track of the layer, preventing the creation of new ones.

Make the following changes:

```
  const markersLayer = useRef(new Paper.Group());
  const floorplanLayer = useRef(new Paper.Group());
```

```
  const trashAllPaths = () => {
    setAllPaths([]);
  };

  const removePath = (id) => {
    setAllPaths((paths) => paths.filter((p) => p.id !== id));
  };

  const savePath = (path) => {
    setAllPaths((paths) => [...paths, path]);
  };
```

```
  markersLayer.current.addChildren([ghostLine]);
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    floorplanLayer.current.removeChildren();
    floorplanLayer.current.addChildren(allPaths);
  }, [allPaths, floorplanLayer]);
```

[image: Edit floorplan-creator (forked)]

Answer (score 0):

The reason it freezes is because `Path` is a heavy object. For what I can see, you have `allPaths`, which is an array of objects that contain the property `id`. I can also see that on a path double click you get the path id.

So, in order to delete a line, I assume this would work:

```
const removeLine = (id) => {
  const allPathsCopy = [...allPaths]
  setAllPaths(allPathsCopy.filter(path => path.id !== id));
}
```

Comment: Thank you Sagi, I did try that before, unfortunately it does not work, it should but it does not. The reason is because when you trigger that method it returns a different `allPaths` array content that it should and I don't understand why? It returns the state of the array the moment that line was created, so if you draw 4 lines and try to remove the third the `allPaths` array will return the first 2 paths that were created before the third, hope that makes sense.